# Controller InheritedResources::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I scaffolded in rails and instead of the general

```
class UtilLegalsController < ApplicationController
```

I got

```
class UtilLegalsController < InheritedResources::Base
```

Anyone know why? Whats the difference? What's the correct option for BAU controller?

Answer (score 10):

May be, you are using gem which includes gem `inherited_resources` (for example `active_admin`). In this case you can generate scaffold with `-c=scaffold_controller` option:

```
rails g scaffold Post user:references title:string body:text -c=scaffold_controller
```

This will bypass `inherited_resources` controller.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you are using a Rails environment that has the [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem installed.
It's not a problem, once this gem, inherits from ApplicationController, and consequently extends it behavior.
If you need more information, please points you browser to the [AsciiCasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/230-inherited-resources) site, for a more complete discussion.